# Как произвольно разбить <ul> на columns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Всем привет! Обычным способом можно разбить "ul" на columns, прописав в стилях списка "columns: 3". Он сделает 3 колонки, по 2 "li" в каждой.
В моем случае нужно сделать это с определенных мест, чтобы выглядело это, как в прикрепленном изображении. Или же как то указать количество "li" в каждой из колонок. Прошу вашей помощи, друзья!

```
<ul>
  <li class="list-item-1">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-item-2">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="list-item-3">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="list-item-4">List Item 4</li>
  <li class="list-item-5">List Item 5</li>
  <li class="list-item-6">List Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как распределяются элементы? в строку или в столбик? пронумеруйте List item'ы чтоб было понятнее)

Comment: Кол-во элементов фиксированное? Они должны каскадом расположиться? Если добавить еще один li - куда он встанет?

Comment: Пронумеровал! В столбик)

Comment: Количество элементов будет фиксированное. Но если добавить еще один li, то он встанет в конец списка, как я предполагаю. Зависит ведь от решения, которое будет :)

Comment: Если вы хотите манипулировать и иметь полный контроль над колонками и содержимым - создайте 3 колонки и помещайте в них значения с помощью jQuery. Если вы хотите сделать, что-то типа газетного отображения блоков, как на Pinterest.

Comment: Дело в том, что в таком виде выводится меню из WordPress. Поэтому ищу решение, чтобы как то расположить его в таком виде. У каждого li есть свой уникальный класс, может это как то поможет.

Comment: @АлексейИнмейк ...

Comment: @Skywave ......

Comment: @foreigndezigner А это wordpress добавляет нумерованные классы или ваших рук дело?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
ul {columns:3}

li:nth-child(4),
li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-column-break-before: always;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list-item-1">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-item-2">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="list-item-3">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="list-item-4">List Item 4</li>
  <li class="list-item-5">List Item 5</li>
  <li class="list-item-6">List Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Всё.

Comment: Идеально, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решил сделать три отдельных li, и в каждый добавить новый ul.

C `margin-padding` и `list-style: none;` уже сами разберетесь)

```js
let ul = document.getElementById('ul');
let li = ul.querySelectorAll('li');

let uls = [], lis = [];
for( let i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
  uls[i] = document.createElement('ul');
  lis[i] = document.createElement('li');
} // Создаю три новых li, чтобы добавить их к основному ul
// И еще три ul, которые добавятся в созданные li

let count = [3, 2, 1]; // Начальное распределение элементов
for( let i = 6; i < li.length; i++ ){
  count[ i % 3 ]++;
} // В случае добавления новых - сверху будет докидываться +1 элем, слева направо.
console.log( JSON.stringify( count ) );

let sum = 0;
for( let i = 0; i < count.length; i++ ){
  for( let j = sum; j < sum + count[i]; j++ ){
    uls[i].appendChild( li[j] );
  } // Все li в промежутке от sum до sum + count[i] — добавляются в созданные ul
  sum += count[i];
}

lis.forEach(function(e, i){
  e.appendChild( uls[i] ); // созданные ul пихаются в созданные li
  ul.appendChild(e); // Созданные li пихаются в основной блок.
});
```

```css
#ul {
  display: flex;
}
#ul > li {
  padding: 0 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="ul">
  <li class="list-item-1">List Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-item-2">List Item 2</li>
  <li class="list-item-3">List Item 3</li>
  <li class="list-item-4">List Item 4</li>
  <li class="list-item-5">List Item 5</li>
  <li class="list-item-6">List Item 6</li>
  <li class="list-item-7">List Item 7</li>
  <li class="list-item-8">List Item 8</li>
  <li class="list-item-9">List Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

P.s. хотя можно было сделать просто три ul и поставить их рядом, а родителя вообще удалить. Но мало-ли, вдруг там еще что-то привязано к этому элементу.